# How to view a jasper report in pdf on running the jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports

[image]

I want to view the jasper report that i created when i run "PDFLEAD.jsp" page. But it is showing like"getWriter() has already been called for this response." and it is displaying as the image given below.The code i tried is as follows

PDFLEAD.jsp

```
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignQuery"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRResultSetDataSource"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRCsvDataSource"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRDocxExporter"%>
<%@page import = "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<%@ include file="/Purchase.jsp" %>

<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.ParseException" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.File" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.FileInputStream" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.FileNotFoundException" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.InputStream" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.FileOutputStream" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.OutputStream" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Map" %>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.*" %> 
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.*" %>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<% 
Connection conn = null;
String sear=(String)session.getAttribute("sea");
String cate=(String)session.getAttribute("cat");
String comp=(String)session.getAttribute("com");

System.out.println("1 is:"+sear);
System.out.println("2 is:"+cate);
System.out.println("3 is:"+comp);

try 
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/marketing_database","root","root");
    String jrxmlFile ="D:/dev/tools/jasper files/report10.jrxml";
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(jrxmlFile));
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);

    System.out.println("Compiling Report Designs");
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

    System.out.println("Creating JasperPrint Object");
    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("complan",comp);
    map.put("search",sear);
    map.put("category",cate);

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,map,conn);
    byte bytes[] = new byte[10000]; 
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    ByteArrayOutputStream Stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint); 
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, Stream); 
    exporter.exportReport(); 
    System.out.println("Size of byte array:"+Stream.size()); 
    bytes = Stream.toByteArray(); 
    response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 1"); 
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 2"); 
    Stream.close(); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 3"); 

    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream(); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 4"); 
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length); 
    outputStream.flush(); 
    outputStream.close(); 

}
catch(Exception e) 
{e.printStackTrace();} 


%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you already used the writer to send `<!DOCTYPE` and other html tags (including System.out)

Remove all html tags as `<html>,<head>,<title>` ecc.

Remove `System.out.println` (this can not be used if your streaming the pdf content)

Replace

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

With

```
<%@ page contentType="application/pdf" %>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
```

and stream your pdf (I would do like this):

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,    
response.getOutputStream());
```

Hence only these 3 commands can be sent to browser...

Comment: Working.Thank You so much @Peter Friberg