# How to pass JasperPrint from Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jasper-reports

I have filled the Jasper report in Servlet. I want to export the PDF/CSV/Excel in the JSP. How to do this?
Is there any method to pass JasperPrint from Servlet to jsp, so that i can export desired files in Jsp.

Comment: PDF/CSV/Excel are not for "export", these are for download. You have to give the client (browser) an URL of the generated file, i.e. most probably the URL of your servlet. Btw. it'd be nice if you shared your code.

Comment: I have answerd a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102974/how-to-view-a-jasper-report-in-pdf-on-running-the-jsp-page/ hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass the object rather give the link of your Servlet behind the Download option i.e. PDF,CSV,Excel.

When someone will click on it. Either it will get downloaded or streamed as you wish.